# Empty list when working with datetimes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
       index  months_to_maturity          asset_id            orig_iss_dt  \
0   529300                   6     (BINARY DATA)  1985-11-29 00:00:00.0   
1   530920                  12     (BINARY DATA)  1986-05-13 00:00:00.0   
2   529302                  18     (BINARY DATA)  1986-11-17 00:00:00.0  

       maturity_dt         pay_freq_cd  coupon  closing_price  FACE_VALUE  
0   2015-11-15 00:00:00.0            2   9.875     103.390625         100   
1   2016-05-15 00:00:00.0            2   7.950     106.017000         100   
2   2016-11-15 00:00:00.0            2   7.500     109.515625         100
```

For each row of `df` there are multiple payments or `coupon`'s between `maturity_dt` and `orig_iss_dt`. These happen every 6 months and I am trying to put them into the list `list_of_coupons`i.e. For every 6 months between the two dates, I want to put a coupon. However, I am currently getting an empty list.

```
#Gets the difference in months between two datetimes
def monthdelta(d1, d2):
    delta = 0
    while True:
        mdays = monthrange(d1.year, d1.month)[1]
        d1 += timedelta(days=mdays)
        if d1 <= d2:
            delta += 1
        else:
            break
    return delta

#Creating the list
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
     list_of_coupons = []
     for k in range(monthdelta(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetime.datetime.strptime(row['orig_iss_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')), 0, -6):
         list_of_coupons.append(row.coupon)
```

Comment: It looks like you want all coupons between `original issue date` and `maturity date`, and it has nothing to do with current date. All of the three records are 30-yr bonds, so why not just do something like `[df.loc[0, 'coupon']]*60` to get a full list of coupons.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big problem with the "#Creating the list" you're resetting `list_of_coupons` to an empty list at the beginning of each iteration. So after you append an item to it, you're erasing it

Try moving it to outside the loop as in:

```
#Creating the list
list_of_coupons = []
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
for k in range(monthdelta(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), datetime.datetime.strptime(row['orig_iss_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')), 0, -6):
         list_of_coupons.append(row.coupon)
```